# How do I create custom ItemReader for each step in my Spring Batch project

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to use a custom reader, processor and writer in each step:

```
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory factory,
                         ItemReader reader,
                         ExpireAssessmentWriter writer,
                         AssessmentItemProcessor processor,
                         PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .<Assessment,Assessment>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    //update aggregate balance table
    @Bean
    public Step step2(StepBuilderFactory factory,
                      ItemReader reader,
                      BalanceItemWriter writer,
                      BalanceProcessor processor,
                      PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .<Assessment,Assessment>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    
    @Bean
    public Step step3(StepBuilderFactory factory,
                      ItemReader<Assessment> reader,
                      CustomWriter3 writer,
                      CustomItemProcessor3 processor,
                      PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step3")
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .<Assessment,Assessment>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
```

The first steps works fine but thats only when I leave this reader in the same class:

```
    private static final String READER_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN='TEST'";

@Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Assessment> reader(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Assessment>()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .name("AssessmentUtilityReader")
                .sql(READER_QUERY)
                .rowMapper(new AssessmentMapper())
                .build();
    }
```

How can I create a custom reader for each of these steps that will read it's own query?

Can I create a custom reader that extends JdbcCursorItemReader
and returns this same snippet of code? :

````
@Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Assessment> reader(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Assessment>()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .name("AssessmentUtilityReader")
                .sql(READER_QUERY)
                .rowMapper(new AssessmentMapper())
                .build();
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the item type is the same for all steps, you can create a method that accepts a query and returns an item reader:

```
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Assessment> getReader(DataSource dataSource, String query) {
   return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Assessment>()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .name("AssessmentUtilityReader") // can be passed as a parameter as well
            .sql(query)
            .rowMapper(new AssessmentMapper())
            .build();
}
```

Then call this method in each step definition and pass the required query for each step.

Comment: Where is the datasource being passed in to the original reader? 
I am having trouble with the getReader configuring the datasource

Comment: For the query param I get 

"required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found."

Comment: I edited the answer to add the datasource as parameter. In each step, you need to call `.reader(getReader(datasource, QUERY))` with its specific query.

Comment: Mahmoud, I responded to the asnwer on my other updated question..
removing @Bean from the getReader() ends in error stating 
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader' in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To Turn your reader in a custom component, which can be autowired, add the following class:

```java
@Component
public class AssessmentUtilityReader extends JdbcCursorItemReader<Assessment> {

  public AssessmentUtilityReader(final DataSource dataSource) {
    setName(getClass().getSimpleName());
    setDataSource(dataSource);
    setRowMapper(new AssessmentMapper());
    // language=SQL
    setSql(
        """
               SELECT *
               FROM TABLE1
               WHERE COLUMN = 'TEST'
               """);
  }
}
```

**Hint:** The Comment (*// language=SQL*) is an hint for IntelliJ to use SQL highlighting in the following lines. It's optional.

Simply autowire in steps definition:

```
@Bean
public Step step3(StepBuilderFactory factory,
                  AssessmentUtilityReader<Assessment> assessmentUtilityReader,
                  CustomWriter3 writer,
                  CustomItemProcessor3 processor,
                  PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager){
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step3")
            .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
            .<Assessment,Assessment>chunk(10)
            .reader(assessmentUtilityReader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
}
```